# getting values from two dynamic textboxes in different Panels

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have two dynamic textboxes in different Panels. When I click the button save it saves multiple records on the system. for example: I have two textbox on each panel. On the Panel 1 lets say it has (a, b) and On the Panel 2 lets say it has (1 ,2). What I'm expecting a result is a1 and b2. but the result goes like this a1 a2 b1 b2 which is wrong. Please help. here's the code of the button.

```
        For Each text2 As TextBox In pnlTextBoxes.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox)()
            For Each text1 As TextBox In pnlTextdesc.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox)()
                Dim con As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("prod").ToString)
                con.Open()
                Try
                    Using cmd As New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO tblProduct (ProductName,productdescription) VALUES (@ProductName,@productdescription) ")
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductName", text2.text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@productdescription", text1.text)
                        cmd.Connection = con
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                    End Using
                Catch ex As Exception
                    MsgBox(ex.Message)
                End Try
                con.Close()
            Next
        Next
```

Answer (score 0):

You get that result because you are using nested `For Each` loops.  If you have two letters and two numbers and, for each letter, you combine it with each number, of course you'll end up with four combinations.  What you should do is create two lists of `TextBoxes` from the two `Panels`, then use a single `For` loop to combine them by index, e.g.

```
Dim list1 = TextBox In pnlTextBoxes.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox)().ToArray()
Dim list2 = TextBox In pnlTextdesc.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox)().ToArray()

For i = 0 To list1.GetUpperBound(0)
    Dim text1 = list1(i)
    Dim text2 = list2(i)

    '...
Next
```

This assumes that there will be the same number of `TextBoxes` in each `Panel` and that they are in corresponding order.

Comment: Can you show me on how am I going to get the values from each panels and how am i going to put it insert it on the database?

Comment: No, because that's not what this question was about.  The issue that you asked about was getting four combinations instead of two and I have answered that.  If you have a different question on a different topic then you need to post that in a new thread with all the information specifically relevant to that issue.  As always though, you don't just posting a question asking how to do something from scratch.  You have to show that you have made an honest attempt for yourself and describe a specific issue with that attempt.